# Has anyone written out the grammar in BNF for the Internet Printing Protocol Collections record described in RFC3382?

Tags: ipp-protocol

I am having a little trouble generating the Collection records described in Internet Printing Protocol definition RFC3382. Has anyone written out the grammar in BNF?

Comment: Do you need the BNF because you chose a lex/yacc-like approach to implement IPP? Or do just consider BNF as a better way to document the message format? My ipp implementation also lacks support for the collections. We could share our work open source. What programming language do you use?

Comment: I am programming in Java for Android. I am writing a general-purpose print service for an instrument that uses embedded Android.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say! I frequently research the internet about IPP and have not come across any work related to IPP and BNF (Backus-Naur-Form) so far.

I guess the [PWG IPP mailing list](https://www.pwg.org/ipp/) would be a better audience for this question. Most ipp implementations don't use a scanner or parser to deal with ipp messages. I assume you implement an ipp server and have covered the ipp parsing already.

Sometimes it is a good approach to capture an ipp message (response) of a real printer and have a look at its byte sequence. On request (personal mail) I can provide such a response in binary format (including a media-col-default and media-col-database attribute)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did do all those things, and will attach an answer I got from the PWG forum.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the Printer Working Group (PWG) site. The short answer is that a RFC-in-progress has a more precise grammar for Collections.

From Michael Sweet:

> There is an updated ABNF grammar in the upcoming RFC 8010 (which
>   replaces RFCs 2910 and 3382) along with better examples that might be
>   of some help.  Here is a link to the authors' review copy (it should
>   be published very soon!):
>
> ```
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/authors/rfc8010.txt
> ```
>
> Sections 3.1.6 and 3.1.7 cover the encoding of the collection
>   attribute and its member attributes, respectively.
>
> FWIW, the "design" of collections in 3382 was done specifically to
>   make them look like a 1setOf attribute with a mix of values so that
>   existing clients/printers could more easily deal with them.  In
>   practice this makes supporting collections a little more difficult
>   (and the encoding of collection values a little more verbose) than is
>   ideal... :/

(Mr Sweet, I apologize for redistributing your information without consulting you)